# Zip file size not changing

Tags: zip

I am zipping a folder after a certain interval of time containing files which are changing in size. But the newly created zip folder has the same size as that of the previous zip folder. Why is the size of the zip folder not changing even if the files that it is zipping are increasing in size?

Comment: How do you determine the size of the zips? Windows Explorer?

Comment: What are the contents of the folder? How are they changing with time?